# what does the sentence means? -->"font:12px/1.5 \5fae\8f6f\96c5\9ed1;", I can't figure out

Tags: html, css

```
body{
    background-color: #ccc;
    font: 12px/1.5 \5fae\8f6f\96c5\9ed1;
}
```

I can't figure out the value of 'font'....

Answer (score 1):

It sets the font to the Chinese font family [Microsoft YaHei](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=350) using unicode characters. The first character here for example is: [5fae](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/5fae/index.htm) and means "small, prefix micro-, trifling". After that I'm lost! Very interesting :)

[image]

Comment: Good call getting the name of the font `:)`

Comment: Thanks @Martin, luckily I speak Chinese and Unicode! ;) haha

Answer (score 0):

Your line is:

font: font size (pixels) / the line height (relative to font size so 12 x 1.5) and then the font family name, the name is chinese characters so is displayed (unicode?) in this way.

You can [read more about this font name here](https://gist.github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=%5C5fae%5C8f6f%5C96c5%5C9ed1)

Overall the CSS line is a shorthand version of standard CSS font declaration, but using a non-latin font-family name.